# jquery: Exiting function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing animation in jquery. I have a looping picture moving from left to right of the webpage. I used following code:

```
 function run() {  $("#run").animate({ left: "980px" }, 250).animate({
  left: "-600px" }, 0);   setTimeout("run()", 250);
 }
```

I want to stop the loop(OR break the function) once I press a button.

Comment: "stop the loop" as in "stop the animation directly"? If so, you can look into `.stop` as well (in addition to clearing the interval).

Comment: setTimeout can take a function as a parameter: setTimeout(run, 250)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) returns a vlaue that can be used to cancel it,

```
//Start
var ref = setTimeout(...);
//Stop
clearTimeout(ref);
```

Also, if just using a function, it is safer to just pass that than forcing an eval,

```
setTimeout(run, 250);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want this animation to run until the user presses a button.  For that I would set up a `setInterval` loop and use `clearInterval` to stop it on the button click

```
var runTimer = setInterval(function() {
  $("#run").animate({ left: "980px" }, 250).animate({ left: "-600px" }, 0);   
}, 250);

$('#stopAnimation').click(function () {
  clearInterval(runTimer);
}
```

Comment: "setInternal" should be "setInterval" for all you copy-pasters :P

Comment: @jbabey thanks, I can't tell you how many times i've made that spelling mistake :(

Answer (score 0):

You want to call clear timeout.

```
var timeout;

 function run() {  $("#run").animate({ left: "980px" }, 250).animate({
  left: "-600px" }, 0); 
   timeout =setTimeout("run()", 250);
 }
 function cancel() { clearTimeout(timeout); }
```

Answer (score 0):

try the method stop() before each animation

```
function run() { 
    $("#run").stop().animate({ left: "980px" }, 250, function(){
        $(this).css('left', '-600px');
    });
    setTimeout("run()", 250); 
}
```

Comment: setTimeout can take a function as a parameter: setTimeout(run, 250)